# How to issue warnings in gitlab pipeline without exit/failure?

Tags: python, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm new to Gitlab and I have come across a case where we would like to issue warnings when a certain event occurs in a job(example: a table was dropped). I would like to know how to achieve this if possible. I explored and came across setting the `allow_failure` flag in `.gitlab-ci.yml`.
But this is not something that I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In GitLab CI/CD pipelines, you can use the 'script' keyword to run arbitrary commands during pipeline run . You can use `echo` command to output warning messages during pipeline run, but these messages will not cause the pipeline to fail or exit .

Example :

```
script:
    - echo "This is a warning message"
```

You can also use the `warn` command which is similar to echo but it prefixes the message with "WARNING":

```
script:
   -warn "This is a warning message"
```

Additionally, GitLab also provides a specific command `warn_only` that will issue a warning instead of a failure .

```
script:
  -
command_that_might_fail
|| warn_only
```